# Pointer-to-a-pointer in C throws segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers

This might sound pretty old school, but I'm still unable to figure out why the following program throws a segmentation fault. Any help would be great

```
#include <stdio.h>
pointer(char **x)
{
    printf ("Before %c",*x[0]);
    *x[0] = 'a';   // segmentation fault here!!
    printf ("After %c", *x[0]);
}
int main()
{
    char *x = "Hello";
    pointer(&x);
}
```

Comment: Look here, it's explained in the top answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

char *x = "Hello";

This declaration makes it read-only. Writing to it the way you tried is illegal.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c) for more information

Answer (score 1):

It's explained in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c).

TL;DR: the memory pointed to by `char *x = "Hello";` is read only. Trying to write to it is illegal, and will result in a segmentation fault.

Comment: Why on earth was this downvoted, 20 days after the answer was posted?